# Constrain an input type in deduction guide

Tags: c++, ctad, deduction-guide

I want my class object's ctor to accept a functor that is able to be converted to a `std::packaged_task<R()>` whereas R is auto deduced from the functor's return value. Here's what I've got so far:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:8,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:8,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:8,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:8,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfuture%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R%3E%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++%0A++++template+%3Cstd::convertible_to%3Cstd::packaged_task%3CR%3E%3E+Cb%3E%0A++++entity(Cb%26%26+fn)%0A++++++++:+++fn_%7B+std::move(fn)+%7D%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++std::packaged_task%3CR()%3E+fn_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+U,+std::convertible_to%3Cstd::packaged_task%3CU()%3E%3E+Cb%3E%0Aentity(Cb%26%26+fn)+-%3E+entity%3Cdecltype(fn())%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++entity+e(%5B%5D%7B+return+10%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <utility>
#include <future>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>


template <typename R>
struct entity
{
    
    template <std::convertible_to<std::packaged_task<R>> Cb>
    entity(Cb&& fn)
        :   fn_{ std::move(fn) }
    { }

    std::packaged_task<R()> fn_;
};


template <typename U, std::convertible_to<std::packaged_task<U()>> Cb>
entity(Cb&& fn) -> entity<decltype(fn())>;

int main()
{
    entity e([]{ return 10; });
}
```

Even though I'm providing a deduction guide, my naive approach doesn't work. I suspect it has to do with the deduction guide specifying `std::convertible_to<std::packaged_task<U()>>` concept where gcc is struggling to substitute U for any type, hence making the deduction guide worthless. Can this be augmented?

```
<source>:12:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:25:30: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'R'
   25 |     entity e([]{ return 10; });
      |
```

Comment: I suppose making the constructors parameter a `std::packaged_task<U()>` is not what you want, as then `entity e([]{ return 10; });` wouldnt work.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Indeed, I would have to explicitely convert the lambda to package task in the API which is not ideal.

Comment: Just have the deduction guide accept the CB, unconstrained, and extract the return type. The c'tor already has the constraint to prevent unwanted callbacks.

Comment: if I understand it correctly `std::is_convertible_to` requires implicit conversion, but there is no implicit conversion (remember a previous question) thats why this https://godbolt.org/z/x58PY8nGM fails too (but not for the deduction guide)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You're both right, now this works as intended: https://godbolt.org/z/YnzjjPhh9]

Comment: you should post that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround. The idea is to first get the return type of the Callable, then check the return type by constraining the constructor.

```
template <typename R>
struct entity {
  template <class Cb> requires std::constructible_from<std::packaged_task<R()>, Cb &&>
  entity(Cb &&fn) : fn_(std::forward<Cb>(fn)) {}

  std::packaged_task<R()> fn_;
};

template <class Cb>
entity(Cb &&) -> entity<std::invoke_result_t<Cb &&>>;

int main()
{
  entity e([]{ return 10; });
}
```

The issue in your code snippet is (I believe):

```
template <typename U, std::convertible_to<std::packaged_task<U()>> Cb>
entity(Cb&& fn) -> entity<decltype(fn())>;
```

`U` is not used in the parameter list of `entity`, thus it is not deduced during the template argument deduction. It tries to deduce `Cb`, but `Cb` depends on `U`.

The generated deduction guide from `entity` constructor has the same issue. `R` cannot be deduced.

Comment: you removed the constraint

Comment: What do you mean by remove the constraint? I admit that I change the constraint, `entity` is constrained by concept `X`.

Comment: `std::convertible_to<std::packaged_task<R>> Cb`

Comment: In the example, `R` is `int`, and `std::packaged_task<R>` is not defined. If you mean `std::packaged_task<R()>`, its constructor is explicit. It is not convertible from a callable in the first place.

Comment: i mean the constraints OP has in their code (yes it has a typo, but anyhow `is_convertible` is the wrong one), the question is how to constrain the constructor argument and have a deduction guide.

Comment: I try to follow the original code snippet as close as possible. But I have to modify the code somehow. The last time I check, my workaround constrains the constructor and has a deduction guide. If you don't like the the concept `X` I come up with, I can use `std::constructible_from`.

Comment: sorry I missed the last edit. now your code has a constraint

Comment: The first version has a constraint too, but anyway. It's aright.

Comment: your first version had no constraint to require that `fn` can be used to cniostruct the `std::packackaged_task`.

Comment: Why did you prefer invoke_result_t instead of decltype?

Comment: OK. I get your point now. I think that I understood your point the moment when I decide to use `std::constructible_from`. But I miss it shortly afterward... Yes, I removed the constraint, my bad. : P

Comment: @glades `invoke_result_t` also works with pointer to member function. It's name is more suggestive than `decltype`.

Comment: @felix Ok, but that would mean I need to arrange the call seperately from the others. That's currently not something I had in mind but I'll think about it.

Comment: Constraint can also be applied to deduction guide BTW [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ebqxv4ozd).